# A linear operator on meromorphic functions

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-forms

I am currently reading Lang's book *Introduction to Modular Forms*, and perhaps I'm wrong, but I may have spotted something weird he said. Either I don't get it, or there's something abnormal about the definition.

Denote $\mathscr{M}$ the space of meromorphic functions defined on the upper-half plane $\textbf{H}=\lbrace\Re(z)>0\rbrace$. For $k\geqslant0$ an integer and $$\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\text{GL}_2^+(\mathbb{R}),$$ define a linear operator on $\mathscr{M}$ by : $$[\alpha]_k\lbrace f\rbrace(\tau)=\det(\alpha)^{k/2}(c\tau+d)^{-k}f(\alpha\cdot\tau),$$ where we defined $\alpha\cdot\tau=\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}$.

Lang is writing :

> In particular, $[\alpha]_k$ depends only on the coset of $\alpha$ modulo scalar matrices.

I agree that this is true if $k$ is even. But in the general case, one has : $$[\lambda\alpha]_k=\frac{|\lambda|^k}{\lambda^k}[\alpha]_k,$$ *i.e.* it depends on the coset of $\alpha$ upon the action of $\mathbb{R}_+^\star$ only, not $\mathbb{R}^\star$.

Now, I agree that upon further reading, one may sweep it under the rug, since there are no modular functions of odd weight. But in the case of modular forms over a **subgroup** $\Gamma$ of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, this need not be the case anymore.

So the question is : is it still the right definition ?

One note though : even though, noting $\pi:\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\to\!\!\!\!\!\to\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, it may not be true that $\pi(\Gamma)$ is a quotient of $\Gamma$ (*i.e.* $\pi:\Gamma\to\pi(\Gamma)$ need not be surjective), when it happens that $\Gamma$ is stable upon the action of multiplication by scalars (so in this case, by $\alpha\mapsto-\alpha$), then it still holds that there are no modular functions of odd weight, since $\Gamma$ contains $-I_2$. Thus in this case, it is still fine to define $[\alpha]_k$ as so and to say that in the cases we are interested in, it only depends on the projective class of $\alpha$. But once again, what if it is not the case ?

Therefore, my worry came from the fact that perhaps Lang didn't *mean* to say that $[\alpha]_k$ depended on the projective class, but rather, it did *only in the cases we will be interested in* ?

Comment: ".. but rather, it did only in the cases we will be interested in ?": Yes I think you are right. For example, if you consider modular forms of half-integer weight the definition you gave of the slash operator is naive and not useful, so Lang probably means the definition works for the special cases of even integer weights.

Comment: I didn't even think half-integer weight modular would be a thing to be honest ! Thanks for the clarification. Do you have any place when I can read about the more general definition you seem to be referring about ?

Comment: Neal Koblitz' book modular forms and elliptic curves has a great chapter on half-integer weight modular forms.

Comment: Thank you very much !